# Docker - setting variable for scope in .env

Tags: docker-compose, environment-variables

I have a `.env` file for my `docker` services, where I set variables like so:

```
SPOTIPY_REDIRECT_URI=http://localhost/callback
```

But scope variables in this case are a string with spaces:

```
'user-read-recently-played user-library-modify playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public'
```

and if I set:

```
SPOTIPY_SCOPE='user-read-recently-played user-library-modify playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public'
```

I'm getting 'illegal scope'.

But it works if I pass the scope as a string bypassing `.env` config, so it must be a syntax issue.

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no special handling of quotation marks. This means that they are part of the VAL. check https://docs.docker.com/compose/env-file/

Try to set the values without quotation marks that could work.

```
SPOTIPY_SCOPE=user-read-recently-played user-library-modify playlist-read-private playlist-modify-public
```